# How to find which files were downloaded from apache logs in centos

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, amazon-web-services

I have the website on Amazon EC2 instance on centos.

I have seen that so much stuff has been downloaded from amazon Network out graph 300GB.

at that time i turned off `apache`

When i type ifconfig then i can also see the Tx bytes there.

But even though i turned off apache , i could still see apache process runnning with `top` command

and my data in ifconfig was still increasing.

Is there any way to find out which files were being downloaded and from where

Comment: Run `ntop` and find out.

Comment: @NathanC where is `ntop` located , is it automatically installed or i have to install it.

Comment: You have to install it yourself.

Comment: @NathanC i have htop installed. do i need ntop or htop will do

Comment: @NathanC , i have installed ntop, how to use it

Answer (score 1):

The answer is dependent on your logging configuration and verbosity.

By default on CentOS, Apache installed using the base yum repos without modification post-install is going to be in `/var/log/httpd/access_log`

Not sure what the default format is, but I believe it will include all HTTP requests, so search for requests for files first (i.e. any path ending in something like .jpg .mp3 .pdf or whatever files you have)

Comment: I ahve many files in access log like pdf. but i am not sure which files are genuine and which are done by hacker

Comment: Are you saying the hacker is requesting files that don't exist? Check the status code of the response, if it succeeded the file exists and was transferred.

Comment: no i am not sure which files hacker downloaded , because in access_log   its not that many , they all look genuine. Is there any other way for hacker to download files. because i remeber when i turned off teh apache even then data was being transmitted any very high rate

Comment: yes. HTTP is only one of many protocols that allow for file transfer, SSH and FTP are going to be two other common ones. you can use `lsof` to see what files processes currently have open.